# How do I parse an email to extract text (password) and store in a variable

Tags: perl, pop3

I have a system that sends an email to a user with a temporary password.  I am using the following script to output the email but I am looking for a way to extract the password and store the value in a variable.  The body of the email will have the following text "Your temporary password is "  I would like to parse the email body and extract .  I assume that I could use a parse module to search for "Your temporary password is" and then store the next token to a variable but my knowledge of perl is not that great.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::POP3;

my $username="user";
my $password="password";
my $host="192.168.17.50";

    # Constructors
    my $pop = Net::POP3->new($host)||
        die "Problem calling Net::PoP->new\n$!\n";

#    $pop = Net::POP3->new($host, Timeout => 60);
    if ($pop->login($username, $password) > 0) {
      my $msgnums = $pop->list; # hashref of msgnum => size
      foreach my $msgnum (keys %$msgnums) {
        my $msg = $pop->get($msgnum);
        my $password = extract_password($msg)||
           die "Problem with extract_password\n$!\n";
        print $password;
        $pop->delete($msgnum);
      }
    }
    $pop->quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that receives the message text and returns the password, or `undef` if it's not found.

```
sub extract_password {
    my $text = shift;

    if ($text =~ /Your temporary password is (\S+)/) {
        return $1;
    }
    else {
        return undef;
    }
}
```

Then you can say `my $password = extract_password($msg_text)`.

Comment: This works if I use a predefined string that contains the pattern but when I run the function on a $msg variable it does not work.  I think I am doing something wrong when assigning different data types or something.  It has been a long time since I've done serious programming

my $msg = $pop->get($msgnum);
my $password = extract_password($msg)||
 die "Problem with extract_password\n$!\n";

Comment: From the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/POP3.html), the `get()` function of `Net::POP3` returns a reference to a list of text lines. You can first combine them to a string using `my $msg_text = join("\n",@$msg)` and then pass that to the function I wrote above.